# Created nested lifetime scope with Unity DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a Web API project that uses Unity as the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver`. The project uses the Unit of work pattern with a single data access layer that is kept in-memory throughout the lifetime of each request. At the end of each request events are fired, I want to execute the events using their own unique data access layer so that they can be run in parallel (sharing causes concurrency issues).

How can I create a child lifetime scope within a Http request context?

I have access to a static instance of `UnityDependencyResolver` which has the method `IDependencyScope BeginScope()`, but given it implements `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver` it seems using that is not the correct option?

With other DI frameworks such as Autofac, it would be:

```
using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();

  using(var nestedScope = scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
  {
    var anotherService = nestedScope.Resolve<IOther>();
  }
}
```

*I would prefer to move the events to a different process and fire via message queues but it is not possible at this time.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity container can [create child container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.createchildcontainer.aspx):

```
using(var scope = container.CreateChildContainer())
{
  var service = scope.Resolve<IService>();

  using(var nestedScope = scope.CreateChildContainer())
  {
    var anotherService = nestedScope.Resolve<IOther>();
  }
}
```

Combine it with [different lifetime managers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507462(v=pandp.30).aspx) ([HierarchicalLifetimeManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507460(v=pandp.30).aspx) for example) and you can your result.

Comment: So how one could register a service for a scoped lifetime, without knowing a priori, what kind of scope is this? For instance an HTTP request is a scope. A PerRequest lifetime manager creates one instance per HTTP request. But lets say I want to use the same service in another scope (I create background task that runs independently of HTTP context). So I need to register the service with a Hierarchical lifetime manager and create a child container for the lifetime of the background task. Now I have a service that should be registered with both PerRequest and Herarchical lifetime. What do I do?